# Fixing a NameError

Tags: python, nameerror

I am writing a program to play tic tac toe with two players. I have gotten the base code done (albeit quite innefficiently), but I keep getting an error saying player2 is not defined. I have tried many things to fix the error but was wondering if yall had any ideas. It is getting caught on the first player1 == player2 condition. Here is the code:

```
   def main():
    board1 = [" "," "," "]
    board2 = [" "," "," "]
    board3 = [" "," "," "]
    game(board1,board2,board3)
def play1():
    global player1
    player1 = int(input("Player 1, where would you like to move? "))
    return player1
def play2():
    global player2
    player2 = int(input("Player 2, where would you like to move? "))
    return player2
def game(brd1,brd2,brd3):
    isvalid = False
    while(not(isvalid)):
        play1()
        try:
            if player1 == player2:
                print("You can't both go to the same spot!")
        except NameError:
            if player1 == 0:
                brd1.pop(0)
                brd1.insert(0,"x")
                print(brd1)
                print(brd2)
                print(brd3)
            elif player1 == 1:
                brd1.pop(1)
                brd1.insert(1,"x")
                print(brd1)
                print(brd2)
                print(brd3)
            elif player1 == 2:
                brd1.pop(2)
                brd1.insert(2,"x")
                print(brd1)
                print(brd2)
                print(brd3)
            elif player1 == 3:
                brd2.pop(0)
                brd2.insert(0,"x")
                print(brd1)
                print(brd2)
                print(brd3)
            elif player1 == 4:
                brd2.pop(1)
                brd2.insert(1,"x")
                print(brd1)
                print(brd2)
                print(brd3)
            elif player1 == 5:
                brd2.pop(2)
                brd2.insert(2,"x")
                print(brd1)
                print(brd2)
                print(brd3)
            elif player1 == 6:
                brd3.pop(0)
                brd3.insert(0,"x")
                print(brd1)
                print(brd2)
                print(brd3)
            elif player1 == 7:
                brd3.pop(1)
                brd3.insert(1,"x")
                print(brd1)
                print(brd2)
                print(brd3)
            elif player1 == 8:
                brd3.pop(2)
                brd3.insert(2,"x")
                print(brd1)
                print(brd2)
                print(brd3)
        play2()
        if player2 == player1:
            print("You can't both go to the same spot!")
        elif player2 == 0:
            brd1.pop(0)
            brd1.insert(0,"o")
            print(brd1)
            print(brd2)
            print(brd3)
        elif player2 == 1:
            brd1.pop(1)
            brd1.insert(1,"o")
            print(brd1)
            print(brd2)
            print(brd3)
        elif player2 == 2:
            brd1.pop(2)
            brd1.insert(2,"o")
            print(brd1)
            print(brd2)
            print(brd3)
        elif player2 == 3:
            brd2.pop(0)
            brd2.insert(0,"o")
            print(brd1)
            print(brd2)
            print(brd3)
        elif player2 == 4:
            brd2.pop(1)
            brd2.insert(1,"o")
            print(brd1)
            print(brd2)
            print(brd3)
        elif player2 == 5:
            brd2.pop(2)
            brd2.insert(2,"o")
            print(brd1)
            print(brd2)
            print(brd3)
        elif player2 == 6:
            brd3.pop(0)
            brd3.insert(0,"o")
            print(brd1)
            print(brd2)
            print(brd3)
        elif player2 == 7:
            brd3.pop(1)
            brd3.insert(1,"x")
            print(brd1)
            print(brd2)
            print(brd3)
        elif player2 == 8:
            brd3.pop(2)
            brd3.insert(2,"o")
            print(brd1)
            print(brd2)
            print(brd3)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only call `play1()` in your loop. You need to `play2()` as well. This won't solve your problems however since `player1` and `player2` are locally defined in there functions. To solve this add `global player1` in `play1()`, and `global player2` in `play2()`. The code then looks like this

```
def play1():
    global player1
    player1 = int(input("Player 1, where would you like to move? "))
def play2():
    global player2
    player2 = int(input("Player 2, where would you like to move? "))
```

And the loop:

```
while(not(isvalid)):
    play1()
    play2() 
    if player2 == player1:
```

Another way you can solve this is to return them, as follows:

```
def play1():
    player1 = int(input("Player 1, where would you like to move? "))
    return player1
def play2():
    player2 = int(input("Player 2, where would you like to move? "))
    return player2
```

Then in your loop:

```
while(not(isvalid)):
        player1 = play1()
        player2 = play2()
        if player2 == player1:
```

This way you avoid globals.

---

EDIT: In order to print the board after each turn, initialize `player2 = None` in the begin of the file:

```
player2 = None
def main():
...
```

You still need the globals in `play1()` and `play2()`

```
def play1():
    global player1
    player1 = int(input("Player 1, where would you like to move? "))
def play2():
    global player2
    player2 = int(input("Player 2, where would you like to move? "))
```

No adaptions to loop are needed then.

Comment: Added the globals in each function, but I still recieve the NameError

Comment: @Alden Did you also add `play2()` in the while loop? I've extended my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: I tried that, but I want it to print the board after each turn, adding play2() right after play1() in the loop does not print the board after each turn

Comment: @Alden Ah ok, an easy way is to initialize `player2 = None` at the top of your code. (I'll put in in my answer, see after EDIT)

Comment: Alright got it up and running! Thanks for your help bro!

Answer (score 0):

Your variables -- `player1` and `player2` -- are defined in local scope (`play1` and `play2`), and you try to access them outside that scope. At the start of your functions, type `global player1` (or `player2`) as its own line to define it in the global scope. Also add `player1, player2 = None, None` on top of all your functions to *initiate* it. As to why `player2` is specified in the error, that's because it is the first variable in the condition, and Python evaluates left-to-right.

Comment: Edited the answer to include setting player1 and player2 to None on top of your functions

Answer (score 0):

As your error says that player 2 is not defined, try adding a `try` `except` condition to check whether player 2 is defined. If it reaches a `NameError`, it could continue the game (printing your board), otherwise, go through your if conditions.

```
while(not(isvalid)):
    play1()
    try:
    # Try going through all your conditions
         if player 1 == player 2:
         ...
    except NameError:
    # But if your player 2 is not defined, go through them all except the player 1 == player 2 clause
         if player 1 == 0:
         .....
             print(brd1)
              ....
```

Comment: I see what you mean. However, I want it to print the board after each turn, if I did what you suggested, would it alternate between inputs?

Comment: I think in that case, you could add a `try` `except` condition. I'll revise my answer to take that into account

Comment: Alrighty, I added those conditions, however when player 1 inputs a position, no piece is placed on the board and the empty boards are printed instead

Comment: We're getting there: so below the `except`, add all your if conditions *that don't include* `if player 1 == player 2` (see my edit)

Comment: okay so that fixed the error, but now the board does not print after each turn

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to see where the problem is without your updated code in front of me; Try making sure your print statements are correctly embedded in your if statements (it should go something like `if player 1 == 0:` `change your board` `print your board` in every one of your `if` statements)

Comment: So it seems that on the second time around, it begins to not print after each move. Ill update my post with the new code so you can see

Comment: again, this is not the most efficient way to write this code (you could replace some of your repetitions with functions, for instance), but as it is, in your `try` clause, go through all your `if` statements (not just the first one).

Comment: Alright got it up and running! Thanks for your help bro!

Answer (score 0):

Its clear from your code that player1 and player2 are initialized on the second line of game method but they are not defined. You may have to define some value.

Add this line

```
player1 = player2 = None
```

Also after looking at your code I suggest try defining the variables to the global scope at start.

```
global player1, player2
player1 = player2 = None
```